# Zero knowledge proof with sum

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

All zero-knowledge protocols I have read so far for discrete log works like this:

1) Prover generate a random number $r$, creates a commitment $t=g^r$ and sends $t$ to the verifier.

2) Verifier generates a random challenge $c$ and sends it to the prover.

3) Prover creates a response $s=r+x*c$ and sends it to the verifier

My question is: is the security affected in any way if, in step 3, the prover responds with $s=r+x+c$?

I don't understand why multiplication $x*c$ is used instead of sum $x+c$.

Comment: Have you actually tried to use $x+c$? What happens to your security proof then?

Comment: $x=s-c$ but that's not the case when you use the random from step 1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what happens if the prover, instead of sending $g^r$ for a random $r$ that he knows in the first round, sends instead $g^{-x}\cdot g^r$ for a random $r$ that he knows?

Comment: Any men-in-the-middle would be able to recover $g^{x}$ and reply to any subsequent challenges.

Comment: This is not the issue here, $g^x$ is public. The point is to see how sending this first flow allows the prover to cheat, I.e., send a last flow that will ne accepted by the verifier, even without knowing $x$.

Comment: He didn't say it was public. Anyway, the result is the same. It can reply correctly without knowing $x$. I don't want to overlap your answer.

Comment: Right, he did not say it, but it is - his question is based on the classical Schnorr protocol, where the goal is to prove knowledge of the discrete log $x$ of a public group element $g^x$ :) But if you saw why it is possible to successfully answer every challenge here, then you got the solution right.